# How to join two tables in django and serialize the same using one serializer?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have been learning django and django rest framework since couple of weeks and I want to figure out how can I join two tables and serialize the data of same to return the json response using django rest framework.

I want to return result as json response:

> {  'user_id_id': 1,     'request_msg': 'Hi',  'response_msg': "Hi, Welcome" }

where result is

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
con = cursor.execute("SELECT backend_request_messages.user_id_id, backend_request_messages.request_msg as request_msg,backend_response_messages.response_msg as response_msg FROM backend_request_messages,backend_response_messages Where backend_request_messages.user_id_id=backend_response_messages.user_id_id=1 ")
```

Here is what I have tried :

```
#backend/Models.py
class User(models.Model):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
      uid = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
      age = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
      active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

      class Meta:
           default_related_name = 'users'

      def __str__(self):
           return self.name

class Request_Messages(models.Model):
      request_msg = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      request_msg_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(
               User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

      class Meta:
            default_related_name = 'request_messages'

      def __str__(self):
          return self.request_msg


class Response_Messages(models.Model):
      response_msg = response_msg = models.CharField(max_length=400)
      response_msg_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      user_id = models.ForeignKey(
                User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

      class Meta:
            default_related_name = 'response_messages'

      def __str__(self):
          return self.response_msg


#backend/serializers.py
class ListSerializer (serializers.Serializer):
      user_id_id = serializers.IntegerField()
      request_msg = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
      # request_msg_created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
      response_msg = serializers.CharField()
      # response_msg_created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)


#backend/views.py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Response_Messages, Request_Messages, User
from .serializers import ListSerializer
from django.db import connection


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def chatbot(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       
       query_set = cursor.execute("SELECT backend_request_messages.user_id_id, backend_request_messages.request_msg as request_msg,backend_response_messages.response_msg as response_msg FROM backend_request_messages,backend_response_messages Where backend_request_messages.user_id_id=backend_response_messages.user_id_id=1 ")
       columns = [column[0] for column in query_set.description]
       results = []
       for row in query_set.fetchall():
           results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

       serializer = ListSerializer(results)
       return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Before answering your question, could you specify the use of ListSerializer, this approach is rather unusual.
Because Django has built-in ways to deal with SQL joins and foreign keys.
so unless necessary I could provide a better way in Django terms, just say so.

Comment: @yovelcohen hey sorry I forgot to show view.py file where i have apiview where I want to  return a json response of the sql query in order to serialize the result fields I am using **ListSerializer** please guide me

Comment: it'll be best if you add that too, so I can under stand better.

Comment: i have added it

Answer (score 1):

About serializers, You should refer to the docs (they're awesome and explain it best).

To give you a direction, I like to create a serializer for every model and if it's related to another model, I refer that in serializer, that way, You can easily customize behavior for each model (although not the only way at all).

So, about serializing I would do the following (notice my comments as well):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import  User

class User(User):
    # Your user class, except, it should inherit Django's User/AbstractUser class.


class RequestMessages(models.Model):
    request_msg = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    request_msg_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='requests_msg')
        # NOTICE THE NEW RELATED NAME, WE'LL USE IT LATER.
    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'request_messages'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.request_msg


class ResponseMessages(models.Model):
    response_msg = response_msg = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    response_msg_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='responses_msg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.response_msg

class RequestMsgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Specify what ever you like...

    class Meta:
        model = RequestMessages
        fields =  # Whatever you like to serialize.


class ResponseMsgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ResponseMessages
        fields =  # Whatever you want serialized.


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Using required = False will cause that every time you create a user they don't have to own messages.
    requests_msg = RequestMsgSerializer(many=False, required=False)
    responses_msg = ResponseMsgSerializer(many=False, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        field = # Same as above ..
```

About your query, using raw SQL in Django is rear, usually, in most cases the Django built-in ORM will do the job and usually faster and better than you.

In your case, if you'll call your query like this for exmaple:

```py
query_set = User.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

the QuerySet object created will hit the DB one for the user object and X queries for all the associated messages with said user, so expensive.

But no need for a custom query with joins and stuff like that, Django has prefetch_related and select_related.

exmaple:

```py
query_set = User.objects.filter(user=request.user).prefetch_related('requests_msg')
```

will reduce all the queries made for request messages associated to a user to only one!

Recap:

I wrote a lot because I'm still learning this stuff myself self and if you teach others you got it!

Refer to DRF's docs about serializers (there's even a dedicated section for nested serializers) and API Views, they really great.

Refer to Django's docs about prefetch related, select related and queries in general, again, Amazing docs that cover everything.

Don't just copy my code or anyone else's, there's no problem with that, just make sure you understand it first if not, you're bound to get stuck with it again!